# Recalculate initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Is there a way to recalculate the initial state for a slice. I am trying to reset the entire store doing:

```
const rootReducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
    // Clear the state
    if (action.type === clearState.type) {
        // Clear all cached api requests
        apiSlice.util.resetApiState();

        // Return initial state
        state = undefined;
    }
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
};
```

The problem is that my auth slice has the following initial state:

```
export const initialState = {
    isLoggedIn: checkIfUserIsAlreadyLoggedIn(),
    email: "",
    status: "idle",
    errorMessage: "",
};
```

So, when I start my application and `checkIfUserIsAlreadyLoggedIn` returns true, then when I reset the store, `isLoggedIn` is still true.

Is there any way I can recalculate the `checkIfUserIsAlreadyLoggedIn` function thus the initial auth slice state?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That would be a side effect within a reducer, which in Redux is strictly forbidden. A reducer should only depend on state and action, not on external data sources.

Also, `apiSlice.util.resetApiState()` will not do anything unless you dispatch it.

Maybe write it all as a thunk instead:

```js
const resetAll = dispatch => {
  dispatch(resetAction())
  dispatch(apiSlice.util.resetApiState())
  dispatch(setLoginState(checkIfUserIsAlreadyLoggedIn()))
}
```